# Opengl texture mapping and image resoution

Tags: opengl, coordinates, bmp, texture-mapping

i'm working with opengl and texture mapping.
the problem is when the applied texture is 512×32 pixels every thing is working fine, but when it's 128×128 the texture is not applied properly.

the texture is not repeated properly, it's applied to the beginning of object and the rest of him is left without any texture.

in the code: length parameter is about 100.

LoadTexture: a function reading .bmp file and returning texture index.

Here's the code i'm working with.

```
int LoadTexture(char *filename,int alpha) 
{
    using namespace std;
    int i, j=0; //Index variables
    static int num_texture;
    ifstream l_file(filename);
    unsigned char *l_texture; //The pointer to the memory zone in which we will load the texture

    // windows.h gives us these types to work with the Bitmap files
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileheader; 
    BITMAPINFOHEADER infoheader;
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;

    num_texture++; // The counter of the current texture is increased

    if(!l_file) return (-1); // Open the file for reading

    l_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&fileheader), sizeof(fileheader)); // Read the fileheader

    //fseek(l_file, sizeof(fileheader), SEEK_SET); // Jump the fileheader
    l_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&infoheader), sizeof(infoheader)); // and read the infoheader

    // Now we need to allocate the memory for our image (width * height * color deep)
    l_texture = new byte [infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4];
    // And fill it with zeros
    memset(l_texture, 0, infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4);

    // At this point we can read every pixel of the image
    for (i=0; i < infoheader.biWidth*infoheader.biHeight; i++)
    {            
          // We load an RGB value from the file
          l_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&rgb), sizeof(rgb)); 

          // And store it
          l_texture[j+0] = rgb.rgbtRed; // Red component
          l_texture[j+1] = rgb.rgbtGreen; // Green component
          l_texture[j+2] = rgb.rgbtBlue; // Blue component
          l_texture[j+3] = alpha; // Alpha value
          j += 4; // Go to the next position
     }

     l_file.close(); // Closes the file stream

     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, num_texture); // Bind the ID texture specified by the 2nd parameter

     // The next commands sets the texture parameters
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // If the u,v coordinates overflow the range 0,1 the image is repeated
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // The magnification function ("linear" produces better results)
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); //The minifying function

     // Finally we define the 2d texture
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);

     // And create 2d mipmaps for the minifying function
     gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);

     delete [] l_texture; // Free the memory we used to load the texture

     return num_texture; // Returns the current texture OpenGL ID
}
```

and Here's how i'm doing mapping  coordinates

```
void drawStreetStraight(Vector2d & point1,Vector2d & point2,Vector2d & point3,Vector2d & point4,double length)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECR); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,streetTexture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex3d(point1.x,0,point1.y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3d(point2.x,0,point2.y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,length/2.0);
    glVertex3d(point3.x,0,point3.y);
    glTexCoord2f(0,length/2.0);
    glVertex3d(point4.x,0,point4.y);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: the range of texture coordinate is from 0 to 1. You cannot add length/2 to it. And why have you given the y coordinate value to z in glVertex3d?

Comment: 1st question: adding length/2 for repeating ie:i want to repeat the texture so i'm doing so (length/2). more than 1 you get repeating effect or clamp (according to your code).
2nd question: my object(road) is laying on XZ coordinates with Y=0, and it's configured with 2-coordinates points(x,y).

Comment: Why is there GL_DECR in glTexEnvf call?

Comment: i tried GL_REPLACE but nothing happened.

Comment: Could you try without mipmapping? And it would be nice to see a screenshot.

Comment: Except for glTexEnvf which should probably be removed completely, everything looks fine... Try gDEBugger or glslDevil ...

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/57929354.jpg
 it's supposed that yellow regions not to be displayed.

Comment: Should not it be "i"? glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);

Comment: Are you sure your texture was loaded correctly? Try to render it on one polygon without tiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a fix for your example, but it appears that you are not using glGenTextures anywhere.

Is there a reason for this?

I prep textures like so:

```
    glGenTextures( 1, &texPlane);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texPlane );
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);  
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texPlanes);
```

Comment: I think you might be right. I was reading comments next to glBindTexture so I hastily presumed that he is providing texture name as a second parameter to the LoadTexture function. Completely missed the code where he is making it up in his function.